# What is the generally accepted pronunciation of “topoi”?

Tags: soft-question, topos-theory, pronunciation

Apologies if this annoys proponents of “toposes “.

It appears to me that there are three main candidates for pronunciation, all focusing on the last syllable:

1. Top-oy (rhyming with “toy” in British English)
2. Top-wa
3. Top-oh-ee (less likely, I feel)

So which, if any, is most commonly used? I do see this as an objective question, in the same way that there is a correct answer to “what is the commonly accepted pronunciation of ‘Lie’?”.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/90848/discussion-on-question-by-nethesis-what-is-the-generally-accepted-pronunciation).

Comment: 'Top-wa' would be French, and it isn't French. 'Top-oh-ee' would be Italian, and it isn't Italian.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The only pronunciation I have ever heard (American) English-speaking mathematicians use is "toe-poy" /ˈtoʊpɔɪ/ (with stress on the first syllable).  That is consistent with the pronunciation of the singular as "toe-poce" /ˈtoʊpoʊs/ and the usual English pronunciation of "oi" /ɔɪ/ (except in words that come from French, which *topoi* does not).

For what it's worth, [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topos) seems to agree with this pronunciation in American English but gives "top-oy" /ˈtɒpɔɪ/ instead as the pronunciation in British English. (To be precise, it gives the corresponding pronunciations for the singulars in American and British English and then mentions both plural pronunciations without saying which dialect they correspond to.)

Answer (score 6):

Topoi is the Greek word "$\tau \acute o \pi oi$", see [wikipedia](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%CF%84%CF%8C%CF%80%CE%BF%CF%82), i.e. the plural of $\tau \acute o\pi o\varsigma$. So the pronunciation is accordingly (I have only heard "toe-poy" so far in English, and we said it this way in school, where the teacher in Greek said it was the original pronunciation in ancient Greece.).

Comment: It is τόποι and not $\tau o \pi oi$.

Comment: I was searching for the accent already, but the backslash accent does not work here (in latex is does).

Comment: Haha sorry, Greek guy here !

Comment: By the way, we use a different $\sigma$ when it's on the end. For that instance, it's τόπος.

Comment: `\varsigma` : $\varsigma$

Comment: The pronunciation is accordingly what? I don't know how to pronounce Greek vowel clusters.

Comment: You said the pronunciation is according to its Greek origin, but that video contradicts what others in this thread have said about how it is pronounced in Greek. So something is amiss.

Comment: @DavidRicherby In our Greek at school we said toe-poy, I am sorry. Perhaps you have a different view on this. The teacher said, this was the original pronunciation in "ancient Greek".

Comment: @DietrichBurde Oh, OK -- I only know modern Greek pronunciation. (Comments deleted)

Answer (score 5):

It is the plural of the word topos which stems from Greek (τόπος in Greek) which is indeed topoi (τόποι). In that case, it's pronounced like to-pee /ˈto.pi/. You give emphasis on the o (that's what the tonos ΄ symbol means over the o). Check [here](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%CF%84%CF%8C%CF%80%CE%BF%CF%82).

Comment: So there is no direct pronunciation of the “o”?

Comment: @Nethesis I'm not good with IPA and stuff, I am Greek so I am trying to make it simple to you on how it is pronounced. It's not like saying the proverb "to" which is read like t-ou (I guess??). It's like saying the to- part from "total" and the pi- part from pizza (this is why I said pee).

Comment: That certainly seems authoritative to me - but I do have some slight hesitancy to accept this answer because the Greek pronunciation of a word does not always align with the most common used pronunciation - so English speakers tend to say “pie” rather than “pee” for $\pi$. Do you know that this is the way the word is commonly said in a mathematical context?

Comment: Well, I have studied only in Greece for the time being, so of course here it is pronounced the right way. Now, regarding the common pronounciation  internationally, I can only guess.

Comment: But that's modern Greek pronunciation. Topos was probably taken from classical Greek. Shouldn't it be pronounced with classical Greek phonetics?

Comment: @enedil Are there any of such phonetics known nowadays? I mean: how on earth can we know how e.g. Odysseus or Homerus would pronounce that? I think we can only speculate on that.

Comment: There are tons of stuff from Ancient Greece but language wasn't always and everywhere the same. But, topos is a standard word from old times and its structure is simple, it is most likely the same since ancient times regarding pronounciation.

Comment: @drhab of course, we can only speculate, but there is some knowledge about it, just look at this Wikipedia article: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ancient_Greek_phonology that being said, I no expert in this matter, I don't know how ancient Greeks would pronounce it, I just expressed concerns.

Comment: @enedil Thank you kindly for the link.

Comment: Essentialy nothing is pronounced based on ancient phonetics. The Greek language is very rich both in conent and in terms of its history (probably the richest), so there's no standard stuff and there are no ancient phonetics. The whole current Greek Language is derived from Ancient.

Comment: @drhab Quite a lot can be said about the phonetics of dead languages, for example through loanwords, rhyme in poetry and onomatopoeia. There is a broad consensus on the phonology of multiple Ancient Greek dialects, Attic in particular. That being said, modern pronunciation of Ancient Greek (derived) words varies wildly, also in Modern Greek.

Comment: @Rebellos I have never heard the word *topoi* pronounced *to-pee* as one would pronounce *τόποι* in Modern Greek, other than by Greeks of course. It has always been *to-poy*, similar to Attic Greek *τόποι* but closer to *τώποι*, except for the very rare French pronunciation *to-pwa*, only heard from a few French undergraduates.

Comment: @Servaes A lot of Greek words aren't pronounced as they should when they are spelled by non-Greek people and have became common. Doesn't mean they are always correct.

Comment: @Rebellos I am aware of that, and that is what I intended to imply with *"modern pronunciation of Ancient Greek (derived) words varies wildly, also in Modern Greek."*. What I also intended to imply is that Modern Greek pronunciation is drastically different from Ancient Greek pronunciation. I was surprised to learn a few years ago that many Greeks are themselves not aware of this.

Comment: @Servaes Of course it is different but there's no such this as Ancient Greek pronounciation, since in different parts of then Greece, had variations regarding to the Greek language (this is why you mentioned Attic Greek - It was the ancient Greek version used in Attica region - now Athens + suburbs + some other parts)

Comment: The English pronunciation of an word borrowed from Greek typically has little if anything to do with its Greek pronunciation, ancient or modern.

Comment: @EricWofsey "Beta", for example!

Comment: @DavidRicherby To the best of my (limited) knowledge, "beta" is nowadays pronounced as "veeta" in Greece, as "beeta" in England, and as "bayta" in the U.S. Is that correct? What about ancient Greece?

Comment: @AndreasBlass That's correct. [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greek_alphabet#Letter_names) says that the ancient pronunciation (as reconstructed later) would have been something like betta (short 'e' as in 'dress').